# Number of steps one needs to infer final height of a walk

Tags: probability

Let us have a walk on $\mathbb Z$ of size $2^n$. To compute the final height of the walk, the trivial way is to sum $1$ for an ascending step and $-1$ for a descending step all along the walk. I would like to have some method to infer the final height in a more efficient way.

More formally, let us denote $\bar h = \frac{h}{2^n}$, where $h$ is the final height. Given an error $\epsilon$ and a probability $p$, I'd like to compute $g$ such that $\mathbb P(\lvert g- \bar h \rvert > \epsilon) < 1-p$, in some "efficient" way (i.e in polynomial time in $n$, and the smaller $\epsilon$ and $p$ are, the more I'll give myself time).

What I have is that if I take $i\in \{1,\cdots,2^n\}$, and set $X_i$ to be $1$ if the $i$-th step is ascending and $-1$ if the step is descending, then the expectation of $X_i$ is exactly $\bar h$. I repeat this $k$ times and set $g = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k X_i$. What should be $k$ for $g$ to be close to $\bar h$ with good probability? I guess this should have the flavour of a Chernoff bound, but all I found on this talks about boolean random variables, and I don't know if I can finish we this. How should I conclude?

Comment: The normal approximation is probably adequate, and will give much less pessimistic bounds than Chebyshev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use Chebyshev's inequality, noting that the variance of $h$ is the variance of a binomial distributed variable which has been scaled by a factor of $2$, since you are using the range $\{-1,1\}$ instead of $\{0,1\}$. Also note you should take $g = \mathbb{E}\bar{h} = 0$.